# Inject a list of processes to execute using spring DI

Tags: java, spring

I have couple of `MessageProcessor`s. One of the `Processor` will log the payload. Other `Processor` will save into an embedded database.

Here is the code I have written so far:

I am using annotation-driven configuration so I have omitted other classes which are not used in this use case.

```
@Component
public class ProcessorConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("textMp")
    public MessageProcessor textMessageProcessor() {
        return new TextMessageProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("employMp")
    public MessageProcessor employMessageProcessor() {
        return new EmployMessageProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    private List<MessageProcessor> messageProcessorList(@Qualifier("textMp") MessageProcessor textMessageProcessor,
            @Qualifier("employMp") MessageProcessor employMessageProcessor) {
        List<MessageProcessor> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(textMessageProcessor);
        list.add(employMessageProcessor);
        return list;
    }
}
```

This class is responsible for all the JMS messages the application receives.

```
public class MessageHandler {
    @Autowired
    private List<MessageProcessor> messageProcessors;

    public void handleMessage(Notification notification) {
        messageProcessors.forEach(processor -> processor.doProcess(notification));
    }
}

public interface MessageProcessor {
    void doProcess(Notification notification);
}

public class TextMessageProcessor implements MessageProcessor {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TextMessageProcessor.class);
    @Override
    public void doProcess(Notification notification) {
        logger.info("The payload is " + notification.getText());
    }

}
```

I have created a builder which takes `String` as input and returns an `Employ` object.

```
@Service
public class EmployMessageProcessor implements MessageProcessor {
    @Autowired
    private EmployDao dao;

    @Override
    public void doProcess(Notification notification) {
        Employ employ = EmployBuilder.buildEmploy(notification.getText());
        dao.save(employ);
    }

}

public interface Notification {
    String getText();
}
```

I think, the way I am injecting the processors can be improved. Please review my code and provide your valuable feedback.

Comment: Does it work as expected so far?

Comment: @Mast : Yes, I do not have any bugs so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a learning exercise for me as well so I hope I can be helpful with my answer.

- I think you can loose the Configuration class entirely. Add
  `@Component`/`@Service` annotation to your `TextMessageProcessor`. Spring should be
  capable of figuring out `MessageProcessor List` wiring on its own. Have you already tried that?

If you are worried about the order of the beans inside `MessageProcessor List` then you can use `@Order` annotation on your `Service` and/or `Component`.

```
@Component
@Order(value=1)
public class TextMessageProcessor implements MessageProcessor {
}
```

- Your Configuration class in its current form is conflicting with Open Closed principle. In other words, whenever you add a new `MessageProcessor`, your configuration will grow. Imagine that configuration after you have 20 processors.
- Spring creates qualifier names automatically as your bean names.
  From Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html):

  > For a fallback match, the bean name is considered as a default qualifier value.
- I recommend doing your wiring through constructors instead of fields  (*I am especially eyeballing that DAO of yours*). That way you preserve an ability to test your code later on. You will need to inject objects through constructors in your tests.
- You could move `Logging` to `MessageProcessor` if it was an abstract class. Make a field or a method for `Logging` which returns the logging instance for current class. ([Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160540/java-logging-with-abstract-classes))

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I agree with all your points but, I am a bit confused with the feedback about Logging. I will do some homework on this and update. Appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: With abstract class you can implement a functionality beforehand. So when that class is extended, it will inherit part of the functionality. You can do the same with interface default method as well though. The advantage of implementing the logging in the PARENT blueprint is that you could force yourself to log in every child element if you deem necessary. Also you would not repeat yourself. TLDR: you don't need to implement logging in children since parent does it for you.

Comment: I happened to think over the advantages and disadvantages of moving `logger` to ParentClass. In the current approach, I have created one Logger instance per class as it is a `static` field. If I change to non-static, every object will have its own instance of `logger` which kinda freaks me out for the classes which serve most common requests in my application. It would be of great help if we get into a chat room and discuss your point of view on this? Please join this https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77498/miko-nukka-dibya